# is there a way to disable update notifications in iWork apps (Pages, Keynote, Numbers)?

Tags: macos, pages, numbers, keynote, iwork

Even with App Store Automatic Updates set to OFF, all of the iWork apps pop up a modal dialog box on startup to inform you there is an update. Is there a way to disable this behavior (in El Capitan)?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you can disable this. It is very easy, although completely unsupported and undocumented by Apple.

1. Install the [PrefsEditor](http://apps.tempel.org/PrefsEditor) application. (You can also do the following steps with Xcode… but ew.)
2. Open PrefsEditor and select the `com.apple.iWork.Pages.plist` bundle.
3. Find the `TSAAUNPersistedState` dictionary and click its disclosure triangle.
4. Edit the `nextAlertPresentationDate` field to some date far in the future (for example, change `2018` to `2030`).
5. Save with `Cmd+S`.
6. Repeat for `com.apple.iWork.Numbers.plist` and `com.apple.iWork.Keynote.plist`.
7. Profit! (No more obnoxious popup dialogs.)

These instructions are summarized from [a wonderful post on MacRumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/heres-how-you-stop-a-free-keynote-pages-numbers-update-is-available-popups.2080712/).